# How to detect if a string has a new line break in it?

Tags: php

This doesn't work:

```
$string = 'Hello
    world';

if(strpos($string, '\n')) {
    echo 'New line break found';
}
else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Obviously because the string doesn't have the "\n" character in it. But how else can I check to see if there is a line break that is the result of the user pressing enter in a form field?

Comment: try replacing '\n' with PHP_EOL.

Comment: Maybe you should use double quotes: `"\n"` or `preg_match('/[\n\r]/')`

Comment: Are you wondering how to submit a form when they hit enter? If so, you won't need to. As long as the submit button made the submit button, it should submit it on an enter.

Comment: Use double quotes.  Single quotes will not interpret the `\n` as a line break, and instead [will consider it a literal `\n`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: CoffeeRain: try pressing shift-enter

Comment: @biziclop Ahh silly mistake. If you post that as an answer I will tick it.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Your existing test doesn't work because you don't use double-quotes around your line break character (`'\n'`). Change it to:

`if(strstr($string, "\n")) {`

Or, if you want cross-operating system compatibility:

`if(strstr($string, PHP_EOL)) {`

Also note that `strpos` will return 0 and your statement will evaluate to FALSE if the first character is `\n`, so `strstr` is a better choice. Alternatively you could change the `strpos` usage to:

```
if(strpos($string, "\n") !== FALSE) {
  echo 'New line break found';
}
else {
  echo 'not found';
}
```

Comment: Isn't it user's computer dependent rather than server dependent what line endings you receive from the dear user?

Comment: I'm just talking in broad strokes ... I try to always uses `PHP_EOL` so my code works in every situation. But you're right if you're dealing with data coming from a user.

Comment: This is a bad answer because PHP_EOL varies between operating systems.

Comment: @rdlowrey, how about if I want to detect if the string starts with line break. Like someone types in textarea field. I tried:

`if(substr($value, 0, 1) == "\n") {
  // code
}`

Answer (score 5):

The most reliable way to detect new line in the text that may come from different operating systems is:

```
preg_match('/\R/', $string)
```

`\R` comes from PCRE and it is the same as: `(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85|\x{2028}|\x{2029})`

The suggested answer to check PHP_EOL

```
if(strstr($string, PHP_EOL)) {
```

will not work if you are for example on Windows sytem and checking file created in Unix system.

Answer (score 3):

line break is `\r\n` on windows  and on UNIX machines it is `\n`.
so its search for `PHP_EOL`  instead of "\n" for cross-OS compatibility, or search for both "\r\n" and "\n".

Comment: If both line breaks contain `\n` then you only really need to search for `\n` to be cross-OS compatible - in order to simply "detect" line breaks.