# php iconv problems with carriage return

Tags: php, iconv

I've got the following code which should escape german special chars. Problem is when someone makes a carriage return in the input field, the code breaks and no text is submitted.

```
<b>Nachricht:</b> ' . iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$_POST["sonstiges"]).'<br><br><br>
```

how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: you can check if it contains a carriage return before it gets to that piece of code. I.e.: `if(strstr($string, "\n"))` or `if(strpos($string, "\n") !== FALSE)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if a string has a new line break in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437121/how-to-detect-if-a-string-has-a-new-line-break-in-it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if string contain ( CR, LF or CF or LF) or not using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398902/check-if-string-contain-cr-lf-or-cf-or-lf-or-not-using-php)

Comment: no thats not a duplicate ... I want iconv as well if there is a cr

Comment: did you not try any of those before posting your comment?

Comment: ok Felix, if you're not wanting to elaborate here then I can't help you anymore than I already tried; good luck.